# 90%, 110% zoom stops jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have pop out menus using jQuery animate.  In Chrome, zoom levels of 90% and 110% prevent the animation from running and the menu is not displayed.  There is no reason the user will want to zoom to this level other than they can.

I have tried rem em and px to no avail. all other zoom levels work fine.

Code:

```
    // Help  ============================================================================
    $("body").on("click", "#btn-help", function(){      
        var el= '#myhelp';
        if($(el).width()!==0){
            $(el).animate({width: '0rem', height: '0rem', opacity: '0'  }, 300);
            $("#fa1").attr('class', 'fa fa-question');
        }else{          
            $(el).animate({width: '30rem', height: '40rem', opacity: '1'  }, 300);
            $("#fa1").attr('class', 'fa fa-times');
        }
    });

CSS:

/* Help Box =======================================================*/
    .help{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 30;
        top: 6rem;
        left: 3.0rem;
        height: 0rem;
        width: 0rem;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #ffc107;;
        border-radius: 1.0rem;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button id="btn-help" class="btn btn-circle btn-warning btn-help" title="Help for this page" ><i id="fa1" class="fa fa-question"></i></button>

    <div id="myhelp" class="help"  style="display:inherit">
        <div class="helpbody"> 
            <p>this is the help text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hope someone can suggest a solution.

Cheers

Bri

Comment: I tried your code, and can find no problem at the zoom levels you talk about. See: http://jsfiddle.net/wvqpxbeu/2/

Comment: Curious, thank you for trying for me KIKO. :). definitely not working on any of my boxes. Hi Res Lo Res.